# es6 import, export default,

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist shows the following code snippet

```
const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer)

export default () => {
  let store = createStore(persistedReducer)
  let persistor = persistStore(store)
  return { store, persistor }
}
```

You could instead do this, and what is the difference between the two?

```
const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer)

let store = createStore(persistedReducer)
let persistor = persistStore(store)
export { store, persistor }
```

- EDIT

more importantly, why would one use the first form instead of the 2nd?

Comment: Well the first thing that comes to mind is that the second snippet is exporting an object, the first a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **first snippet** is exporting a `function` which returns a `object`. The **second snippet** returns a `object` directly.

When import first snippet, You need to call the function to get the object. Meanwhile You can directly import object from second snippet.

Comment: ok so the intention of the first one is to delay the execution of  `  let store = createStore(persistedReducer)
  let persistor = persistStore(store)` until the point of the function call (exported function)?  

The code `  let store = createStore(persistedReducer)
  let persistor = persistStore(store)` runs only once in either of these?

Comment: The first one will not run when you import until you call. When you call it delays the execution of  `let store = createStore(persistedReducer) let persistor = persistStore(store)`.

Answer (score 0):

`vi a.mjs` then write:

```
export default () => {
  let store = 'createStore';
  let persistor = 'persistStore';
  return { store, persistor }
}

let store = 'createStore';
let persistor = 'persistStore';
export { store, persistor }
```

`vi b.mjs` then write:

```
import a from './a.mjs';
import * as $a from './a.mjs';
import { store, persistor } from './a.mjs';

console.log('export default function:', a);
console.log('export object:', $a);
console.log('export object.default:', $a.default);
console.log('export { store, persistor }:', store, persistor);
```

`node  --experimental-modules b.mjs`

And the you will be get the result like this:

```
export default function: [Function: default]
export object: [Module] {
  default: [Function: default],
  persistor: 'persistStore',
  store: 'createStore'
}
export object.default: [Function: default]
export { store, persistor }: createStore persistStore
```